# Python mysql save with special char mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I've tried to make a program using python & _mysql lib, but when I save special character in my database will return "\xblablablablabla\x0etc..."

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import _mysql
import md5
crypt="LOLOLOLOLOLOLOLOL_I<3U"
def Create_Table():
    db = _mysql.connect("localhost","Test","Password")
    db.query("CREATE DATABASE Meow")
    db = _mysql.connect("localhost","Test","Password","Meow")
    db.query("CREATE TABLE Login(Login TEXT,Password TEXT)")
    db.commit()
    db.close()
def AddLogin():
    Login = raw_input("Login : ")
    Password = raw_input(" Password : ")
    m = md5.new()
    m.update(Password)
    m.update(crypt)
    Password = m.digest()
    db = _mysql.connect("localhost","Test","Password","Meow")
    db.query("INSERT INTO Membres(Login,Password) VALUES ('"+Login+"','"+Password+"'")
def Show():
    db=_mysql.connect("localhost","Test","Password","Meow")
    db.query("SELECT * from Login")
    result = db.store_result()
    result = result.fetch_row(0)
    print result[0][1] # exemple
```

This is an example.

Comment: **WARNING**: MD5 for passwords is **extremely weak**. At the very least use something like [Passlib](https://bitbucket.org/ecollins/passlib/wiki/Home) which does this properly.  You also have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because you haven't [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/python.html) anything.

Comment: Thank for  your reply, I'll try

Comment: That's okay but same issue, when I read from my script I have /xblablabla

But in my database that's correctly write